# Setting up Parse in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I am having some difficulties setting up the Parse framework in iOS. I have set up all the libraries, linked frameworks etc... The specific issue is that I cannot get the subclasses to autocomplete anything related to parse

I have included the libraries...

[image]

I have linked the frameworks in build phases...

[image]

I want autocompletion similar to this...

[image]

But I get nothing related to the Parse framework!!!!

[image]

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I have used parse before doing the same thing, but now its not working. Anyone know whats up?

Comment: Oh you're trying to create some sort of Parse file? Is that what you want the autocomplete for?

Comment: Yes, No need to import. What I want to do is create a class that subclasses PFQueryTableViewController

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, it should come up. Have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: like 10 times lol... its soooo frustrating! ... also tried restarting xcode

Comment: hmmm... i cleaned the project again.. now I get things like PFQuery and some other PF related things... but I still cant get PFQueryTableViewController

Comment: @JoshEngelsma save yourself all of this hassle by using Cocoapods. http://cocoapods.org

Comment: @Fogmeister I actually just learned about Cocoapods a week ago... at first I was not seeing a huge benefit, but after going through this annoyance, I am definitely moving that direction with my apps in the future

Comment: @JoshEngelsma it manages any dependencies on other third party frameworks too and sorts out header search paths and all of that stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I finally figured out something that works...

Because parse recently split up their frameworks into multiple frameworks you need to include both Parse.framework and ParseUI.framework. This step I had done correctly. BUT, in addition, you need to import the ParseUI framework in the AppDelegate file to get visibility for auto completion of the ParseUI headers... hopefully this mistake on my part saves someone else a headache

I just did the `#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>`

in my AppDelegate.m file...

[image]